# Correlation Between Binary Variable and Continuous

Tags: correlation, categorical-data, binary-data

Y is a binary variable (0 or 1) and X is a continuous variable.

What would be the best way to check how these variables are correlated?

Specifically, I'd like to check if the distribution of X | Y=0
 (X given Y=0) is significantly different from the distribution of X | Y=1 (X given Y=1).

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: It depends on what these variables represent, on your study objectives, and what you mean by "correlated."  A large number of similar questions have been posted and answered, so [take a look at them](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=binary+continuous+correl*+answers%3A1).

Comment: Thanks @whuber . My binary variable is an indicator of presence of a person at an event or place, and X is it's salary level. I want to check if the distribution of X | Y=0 (X given Y=0) is significantly different from the distribution of X | Y=1 (X given Y=1).

Comment: Then you should look into linear regression using the binary $Y$ as a dummy. Can you show us a plot of the data?